# .bashrc function with arguments

Tags: bash

I often use the following command to merge PDFs:

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -sOutputFile=output_name.pdf /location/of/plots/*.pdf
```

I tried setting up an equivalent function in my .bashrc file:

```
function(){
  gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -sOutputFile=$1 $2
}
```

Now, `$ function output.pdf input.pdf` only takes one input. How can I change that? Ideally I'd like to be able to pass `*.pdf` as input.

Comment: Why do you say that it only takes one input? Bash function can take as many parameters as you want.

Comment: Can you try passing arguments by double-quoting them `$ function "output.pdf" "input.pdf"`

Comment: @Inian Thanks, that works!

Comment: @Demosthene: Please accept the other answer, and remove mine's so that I can delete that as it seems doesn't solve your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following function works fine for me:

```
pdf_merge() {
    output=$1
    shift
    gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -sOutputFile="$output" "$@"
}
```